# How to remove secure cookie from cors domain

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, cookies, cross-domain

I am using react (on netlify) and express (on Google Cloud Run) together. With react and CORS I need to set the `cookie=secure` and `samesite=none` in order for chrome to add the cookie on the front end. This is fine but I am unable to remove the cookie using document.cookie = `'test="";-1; path=/;'`. It does not even show up when I use `document.cookie` to list out all current cookies.

Note this is secure and not `httponly=true`, which I though were the only ones you could not modify from the front end, like another cookie I am sending from express.

In short I want to be able to set two cookies from express on google, one `httponly=true` and the second to be modified from the front end (front end can destroy the second cookie) but I cannot set secure to false as google will not allow that cookie to be added due to CORS.

How would I be able to achieve this, adding a non secure cookie to chrome with CORS and be able to modify it from the front end?

Code I am using to set the cookie:

```js
res.cookie("test", testValue, {
            maxAge: "2000",
            secure: true,     //If I do not set these two lines chrome does not accept it.
            sameSite: "none", //If I do not set these two lines chrome does not accept it.
        });
```

I will also add that if I attempt to use the expire method as suggested by Heiko Theißen, in the below code nothing happens. If I attempt to set it to a different value with the new value method, a copy of the cookie as added with the same name instead as shown in the screenshot. Both methods work when using localhost in dev. It is only in production with the `cookie=secure` and `samesite=none` flags set that both these methods no longer work.

```js
//Expire method
document.cookie="test=;Expires=" + new Date("1970-01-01").toGMTString();

//New value method
document.cookie = 'test="";-1; path=/'
```

[image: Duplicated cookie when using new method]

Comment: Does the domain of the cookie (Google Cloud run) match the domain of the HTML page where your Javascript runs (Netlify)?

Comment: No it does not. So thats why `samesite=none` is set and `samesite=none` needs `secure=true` else Chrome rejects the cookie

Comment: I suspect that the cookies cannot be manipulated from Javascript across origins. Can you post details of the request whose response contains the `Set-Cookie`?